# 403 forbidden access to extracted .war file (started from manager)

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu-18.04

I'm fairly new to using Tomcat so I'm sure I'm missing something.

I have managed to run Tomcat on Ubuntu 18.04 and opened up the manager page, added a .war file which extracted perfectly and got displayed in the manager page(running=true)

However when I try to open up the app from the browser using the exact path it returns a 403 forbidden error with this in the description `The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.`

What do I do to get it working

I have tried `chown tomcat8:tomcat8 <foldername>` and when I tried to refresh the browser the error message changed to 404 not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely not a filesystem issue. What is most likely happening is the application requires authentication. Couple of ways to determine this... the best is to read the documentation. You can also look at the source code. Unzip the war and look in the WEB-INF directory, and you should see a web.xml. In that you'll see a security-constraint and roles sections. You'll need a user with those roles.

Tomcat can authenticate against a local database. In the conf directory, there will be a tomcat-users.xml you can add users to (there is examples in that file). Once you've created users, restart tomcat and try logging in with one of those users.

Comment: Thanks for the help mate, I'll give it a dive and let you know